Unable to Use NiFi Processors in MiNiFi despite Building with JNI Enabled
I built Minifi binaries from source, ensuring that JNI was enabled (DENABLE-JNI=ON). However, I'm encountering difficulties using NiFi processors, such as ExecuteStreamCommand, within MiNiFi.
ExecuteStreamCommand is not available in Minifi by default build
List of available processors in MInifi by default
So its suggested hat I should use Flag DENABLE_JNI = ON while build process.
Documentation
After building MiNiFi with JNI enabled, I expected to be able to utilize NiFi processors seamlessly within MiNiFi, including ExecuteStreamCommand.
As per the build documentation I should be able to access Nifi Processors within minifi if I use DENABLE-JNI=ON during Cmake
I need ExecuteStreamCommand in minifi, is there any way to do it?
ExecuteStreamCommand
Build process I followed
ERROR LOGS:
[2024-04-11 15:43:32.654] [org::apache::nifi::minifi::internal::RocksDatabase] [info] Opening rocksdb database '/home/vignesh/MINIFI/JNI/nifi-minifi-cpp/build/nifi-minifi-cpp-0.15.0/content_repository'
[2024-04-11 15:43:32.670] [main] [info] setting default dir to /home/vignesh/MINIFI/JNI/nifi-minifi-cpp/build/nifi-minifi-cpp-0.15.0/content_repository
[2024-04-11 15:43:32.670] [org::apache::nifi::minifi::Properties] [info] Using configuration file to load configuration for  from conf/bootstrap.conf (located at /home/vignesh/MINIFI/JNI/nifi-minifi-cpp/build/nifi-minifi-cpp-0.15.0/conf/bootstrap.conf)
[2024-04-11 15:43:32.670] [org::apache::nifi::minifi::Properties] [info] Using configuration file to load configuration for  from conf/bootstrap.conf (located at /home/vignesh/MINIFI/JNI/nifi-minifi-cpp/build/nifi-minifi-cpp-0.15.0/conf/bootstrap.conf)
[2024-04-11 15:43:32.671] [org::apache::nifi::minifi::utils::crypto::EncryptionManager] [info] Using existing encryption key for 'nifi.bootstrap.sensitive.properties.key'
[2024-04-11 15:43:32.671] [main] [info] Loading FlowController
[2024-04-11 15:43:32.671] [org::apache::nifi::minifi::FlowController] [info] Instantiating new flow
[2024-04-11 15:43:32.672] [org::apache::nifi::minifi::core::FlowConfiguration] [error] No Processor defined for org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand
[2024-04-11 15:43:32.672] [org::apache::nifi::minifi::core::flow::AdaptiveConfiguration] [error] Could not create a processor ExecuteStreamCommand with id 63701ada-a716-3b70-0000-000000000000
[2024-04-11 15:43:32.672] [org::apache::nifi::minifi::core::flow::AdaptiveConfiguration] [error] Error while processing configuration file: Could not create processor ExecuteStreamCommand
[2024-04-11 15:43:32.672] [main] [error] Failed to load configuration due to exception: Could not create processor ExecuteStreamCommand
[2024-04-11 15:43:32.675] [main] [info] Runtime was 82334832ns


I see a lot of documentation links and zero actual output and errors. Edit your question with an actual error message and steps to reproduce your error.

Did you also follow the steps for configuring the JNI plugin? It looks to me like it tells MiNifi where to actually find the nifi code.

Hi @Botje,
I should get nifi-standard-nar from Nifi and place it in /example/dir and configure nifi.nar.directory=/example/dir and start cmake build process right?
This is what i actaully did
To be honest, the steps in the readMe is not detailed enough and no examples can be found on web on my requirement.

I would expect the nifi jar locations to be runtime configuration. Sometimes you have to figure things out by reading the documentation and the code.
